# How to use MultiDetector in android ML kit

Tags: android, kotlin, barcode-scanner, google-mlkit, text-recognition

I would like to implement Barcode and Text detection same time using android ML kit. How can I implement this?

Comment: By passing your `InputImage`s to both of them? It's not clear exactly what you're having trouble with.

Comment: @Michael I got answer.

 I am calling 

Tasks.await(result) right after the recognizer.process()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tasks.await(result) right after the recognizer.process()